# What's the combat bounty for destroying the weapons of a capital ship?

Tags: elite-dangerous

I read somewhere that you can destroy the weapons of a capital ship. What is the bounty for that?

http://elite-dangerous.wikia.com/wiki/Majestic_Class_Interdictor

Answer (score 1):

Routing a Capital Ship nets a 150,000 credit cash reward, according to the [patch notes for Elite: Dangerous 1.5/2.0](https://forums.frontier.co.uk/showthread.php?t=211781):

> - Cash reward for routing a capital ship is now 150000 instead of 50000 to bring it in line with other increases in combat bonds

This requires you to destroy all of the heat relays on the ship. This will trigger a thermal cascade, and force the ship to retreat from the battlefield.

You do not get anything for destroying an individual capital ship component.

Comment: Also, based on the videos I have seen, I'm guessing the player that gets the final hit on the final relay gets the bond.

Comment: Hardly seems worth it when you can easily get that for killing an NPC pirate,

Comment: It's more of a pride thing, I feel. So you can upload a video of you and your friends routing a capital ship.